# Create Email with a workflow in MS Dynamics Crm 2011 and dynamically fill the "To" field

Tags: email, workflow, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm working on Ms Dynamics Crm 2011 development and I encountered following problem.
My situation:

I want to be able to automatically send an Email after a change on a specific status field on a record of the Entity "MyEntity". "MyEntity" has an Email-field. I try to create a workflow which sends an Email to  the Email-field address of the "MyEntity" record after the status has been changed. My problem is that I can't add in the Email Creation workflow to the "To" field this "MyEntity" Email-field adress. I need to somehow specify in the workflow to dynamically add the "To" field, the relating Email address from the specific "MyEntity". Is that possible? Is there a workaround for that? It could be done with a plugin I guess, but by now I'm trying to avoid the plugin solution.

Thanks in advance

John

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to.  First go to Solutions, bring up your entity, go to Fields, bring up your e-mail field and ensure the Format is e-mail.  Publish.

Work around:  If you have more than 1 e-mail Format text field, change the others temporarily (to text from e-mail) and Publish.  Otherwise, the next step is ambiguous and we don't have control over which field CRM sets up as the email to use when this entity is used for e-mail.

In the solution frame, select your entity node in the tree.  Under Communication and Collaboration, check the box 'Sending e-mail (If an e-mail field does not exist, one will be created).'  Save/Publish.

Fix the work around above if you had more than 1 e-mail format text field.  Change them back to e-mail.  Publish.

In Workflow, select your To Field.  Under the Send e-mail step, select 'Set Properties.'  Select the 'To' field.  In the form assistant you should not be able to select your entity.  NOTE:  You will bind to the 'Key' field and NOT to the particular e-mail field.

This only works for a single e-mail field on your custom entity.  There is no way to use a text field as an address in a CRM 'to' field.

Comment: I have never thought that there is a work around.
Useful information for me.

Comment: I wish I could have used this solution but the "Sending e-mail (If an e-mail field does not exist, one will be created)" checkbox is disabled for the Case entity.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot.

Out of the box the **To** field in an email accepts only

- Account
- Contact
- Facility/Equipment
- Lead
- Queue
- User

So in order to achieve the goal , you will have to write a custom workflow activity (optional : taking the custom text field in your input  parameter )and refer it in your workflow or develop a plug-in.

**Sample code for Plugin**:

```
SendEmailRequest req = new SendEmailRequest();
req.EmailId = emailId;//ID of created mail
req.TrackingToken = "";
req.IssueSend = true;
```

For more information check this post [Crm 2011 :Workflow - Sending email problem](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/crmdevelopment/thread/375f5dad-0382-4112-ab0d-5b42ba235d96)