# How to create lookup field for e-mail template entity?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I want to add new field on my custom form.
It should be 'Lookup' type and with target record type 'Email template'.
By default, CRM 2011 doesn't contains this entity in target records list.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940170/create-email-with-a-workflow-in-ms-dynamics-crm-2011-and-dynamically-fill-the-t

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't help.
I need to relate case with email template on some way. It would be ideal to just create lookup field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do what you are looking for in that manner. If your goal is to ultimately send and email using the template you would have selected in your Lookup, you might try replacing it with an Option Set with values relating to your templates. Then in a workflow, you could check which item was selected in a Check Condition and then for each call the Send Email action specifying the template that corresponds to your selected value.

Comment: So then the email template to use would be hardcoded into a workflow? This isn't an option for me as the point of this exercise was to make sure users could select/create an appropriate templates for workflow automated emails (confirmation email template, cancellation email template etc..) am I to understand this isn't possible?

Answer (score 2):

We have the same requirement for a client and managed to solved it.  We built a Silverlight control that shows all the email templates and when clicked, it saves the GUID of the Email Template into a string field.

When the process runs to send the email it converts the string back into the GUID to get the Template record.